# Are there some private library apps that can connect to a custom DB?

Tags: database, api, app

I have a couple thousand books and I have been organising them since COVID broke out. I have been using BookBuddy+, but sadly its API is borderline non-existent and now that I am planning to sell some of the books, I'd like to build my own DB which I can use for e-commerce and automated catalogue generation and I need an app that can populate it. I don't really care about the DB it connects to, since I know my way around the more popular ones.

The app in question should be able to scan ISBN barcodes and retrieve corresponding book's data. As I said, it should be able to connect to a DB or at least have an API of its own. That's it, the rest I can take care of. I am ready to pay for the app. Any ideas?

Comment: You didn't specify what OS that "app" shall run on, nor how much you'd be wiling to spend on it. If Android is fine, maybe take a look at my list of [inventory apps for books](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_barcode_inventory#group_33). Not sure which ones can connect to a custom DB, but I guess some of them would use at least an internal SQLite DB which you might be able to extract then. Several of hem are open-source, so you could even adjust them to your needs.

Comment: I didn't specify because I have access to all common platforms due to my day job, so everything goes, but thank you for pointing it out and thank you also for your list, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not the first facing this problem, so look at what other users do:

- There are plenty of [Plugins for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-books-gallery/) that can be much better than BookBuddy+
- You can search directly into the [WordPress Plugin list](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/tags/books/)
- They also offer [Mobile App](https://www.jotform.com/blog/wordpress-plugins-for-librarians/)
- And you can also find [Themes for it](https://codecanyon.net/category/wordpress?term=book%20library)

So if the goal is the e-commerce I would start from there and then think about the best tool to feed the e-commerce. Not the other way around.

Comment: These are all great tips, thank you!